# Modify Exception Handling using Hooks in Dancer

Tags: perl, exception, dancer

I'm trying to set up a hook to catch all exceptions and errors thrown from my Dancer application ( an API ) and pass them to a function that sets the HTTP status code and returns the hash ( serialized as JSON ).

Everything works fine when I use try/catch, but when I move it to a hook it runs the code but the response is formed using the default error mechanism instead of my function.

This is the hook I'm using:

```
# Handle errors
hook on_handler_exception => sub {
    my $e = shift;
    debug "ON HANDLER EXCEPTION";
    return API::Exception->handle($e); # sets status code and returns hash depending on the exception
};
```

I also tried using `halt` instead of return to stop any further processing of the exception but it didn't alter anything.

How would I accomplish this with Dancer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use the "on_route_exception" hook instead ...

```
hook on_route_exception => sub
{
    my ( $exception ) = @_;
    error( $exception );
    status( 'error' );
    halt( { errors => [ { message => 'An unhandled exception occurred', code => 0 } ] } );
};
```

Comment: is on_route_exception always invoked on every exception?  when *would* you use on_handler_exception?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code of [Dancer::Error](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/XSAWYERX/Dancer-1.3110/lib/Dancer/Error.pm).

I think something like

```
my $content = Dancer::Engine->engine("template")->apply_renderer($template_name, $ops);
    return Dancer::Response->new(
        status => $self->code,
        headers => ['Content-Type' => 'text/html'],
        content => $content);
```

from the  `_render_html` method could help you.